# Can you prompt for user input in a shell script that is running remotely?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I have a script that will be run on a remote machine.
While running, the script computes some value. 
I want to prompt the user so she can change this value if needed.
Is this possible?

I am running the script like: `ssh $usr@$machine 'bash -s' < a.sh "param1" "param2"`

In a.sh the `read alternateValue` function call seems to be ignored.

Or can anyone suggest a different approach?

Comment: Where do you want the prompt to show up for the user?  Do you want a window to pop up?  Do you want them to be able to open a terminal and see the prompt?  Do you want the prompt to find an existing terminal and try asking whoever is using it?

Comment: From my workstation I want to run the script which will connect remotely and execute some several commands. I'd like to be prompted on my workstation.

Answer (score 3):

The `read` statement reads data from *stdin*, but you are redirecting *stdin* in your command line with the `<` operator, so `read` isn't going to do anything useful.

What if you were first to *copy* the script over to the remote host, and then run:

```
ssh $usr@$machine 'bash /path/to/a.sh param1 param2'
```

Because there is no redirection happening here, `read` would work without a problem.